# Discontinuous pressure elements for incompressible Navier-Stokes

Tags: finite-element, fluid-dynamics, navier-stokes

I am looking for some LBB-stable velocity-pressure combinations for incompressible Navier-Stokes where the pressure space is element-wise discontinuous, preferably with a linear variation elementwise. I can think of two options: (i) Discontinuous Galerkin and (ii) Crouziex-Raviart element, but I am not sure which one would be better. I would also like to learn about other options. Are there any shortcomings of CR elements for incompressible Navier-Stokes? I would appreciate any insights that can help me make the decision.

Note that I will be using this element for developing a solver for the fictitious domain method in which the velocity at the boundary of the immersed solid is imposed using distributed Lagrange multipliers, similar to [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0045782515004296). I am interested in both quad and tria elements for 2D problems, and tetra and hexa elements for 3D problems. I have a coupled velocity-pressure-multiplier solver already implemented for Taylor-Hood elements and b-splines.

Comment: Stabilized method should work for any conforming finite element spaces. Also I think the MINI-element can be generalized to P2+bubble-P1d. What do you exactly mean by CR, i.e. what is the velocity/pressure pair?

Comment: Thank you, @knl!
If by stabilised method, you meant pressure stabilisation, then it spoils mass conservation when used with Lagrange multipliers. If not, could you please elaborate on the kind of stabilisation you meant?

Comment: To be honest, I do not know the exact meaning of an extended (second-order) Crouziex-Raviart (CR) element. I have seen different sets of basis functions being used with the name Crouziex-Raviart element, the element combination you mentioned being one of them. Others use one pressure DOF + two spatial derivatives of pressure (in 2D) per element. So, I am perplexed. I would like to know what exactly is a second-order CR element.

Comment: @Chenna K: If I remember correctly, the lesser-known second-order element proposed in the same paper by Crouzeix and Raviart is conceptually different. It is thus quite confusing to refer to it as 2nd order CR. Adding the bubble - which they do to achieve uniform LBB stability - also sacrifices pointwise incompressibility.

Comment: Thanks, @ChristianWaluga! Your comment summarises my confusion with the higher-order CR element. I have been going through various papers but didn't find any paper that clearly explains all the basis functions for the higher-order CR elements, in a way that we have for Lagrange elements. Please let me know if you know of any such resources.

Comment: @knl, do you know of any papers with a comparison of computational cost for the P2+bubble-P1d element with other elements, e.g. P2-P1, MINI etc.?

Answer (score 3):

There are many variations of the idea of Taylor-Hood elements that remain stable.

- The Taylor-Hood element on quadrilateral and hexahedral elements are generally understood (though historically incorrect) to be the space $Q_2\times Q_1$ for velocity and pressure.
- But this is not optimal: We can make the pressure space larger and instead use $Q_2 \times P_{-1}$ where $P_{-1}$ is the set of discontinuous functions that are *linear* in every coordinate. This can be interpreted in two different ways, namely that $P_{-1}$ is constructed directly on the actual cell in terms of the real-space coordinates, or one can think of it as the set of linear shape functions mapped from the reference to the real cell. There are subtle differences in the convergence theory for these two. The place to read up on these elements is the book by Volker John ("Finite Element Methods for Incompressible Flow Problems", Springer 2016), as well as  the article by Matthies and Tobiska: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs00607-002-1451-3)
- One can also use discontinuous elements for the velocity, and one example of such approaches can be found in the paper by Cockburn, Kanschat, and Schoetzau: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10915-006-9107-7

Comment: Thanks, @Wolfgang Bangerth! I thought $Q_2 \times Q_1$ is with continuous approximation. Did I learn it wrong?

Comment: Regarding the $Q_2 \times P_{-1}$ element, I used it with a mixed formulation for solid mechanics problems. Its accuracy is poor. But, it seems to be an easier option in terms of implementation, considering that I already have a code for $Q_2 \times Q_1$ element.

Comment: Concerning the $RT_{k}/Q_k$ elements considered in that paper by Cockburn et al., could you provide me with some resources with the details of basis functions?

Comment: $Q_2\times Q_1$ uses continuous elements for both velocity and pressure, and is what is commonly referred to as the "Taylor-Hood element". If you made the pressure discontinuous, i.e., $Q_2\times Q_{-1}$, you would get an unstable element. It has one pressure degree too many per cell in 2d; but $Q_2\times P_{-1}$ is stable.

Comment: Regarding $RT_k \times Q_k$, what is your specific question? $RT_k$ are the usual Raviart-Thomas elements whose basis functions are easy to find.

Comment: Thanks, @Wolfgang Bangarth! I have been looking for the basis functions of higher-order RT elements. I didn't find it easy. Appreciate if you could point me to one such resource which gives explicit expressions for the basis functions of RT elements at least up to order 3.

Comment: They are tensor products of functions $Q_{k+1}\times Q_k$ for the x-component of the vector and the other way around for the y-component. Then you need to map them forward via the Piola transform.

Comment: In general, the FEniCS people behind the "Periodic Table of Finite Elements" have been doing a good job at collecting this information. I would look things up there.

Comment: I did my research before posting here. Giving a table with the names of the elements is not the same of as providing all the details. Do you know of any resources that decode these cryptic mathematical statements for the Engineers like me? If you know any documents with the details of basis functions, then please point to them.

Comment: What I meant is that the periodic table of elements is part of a paper that I imagine has all of the relevant references to papers that provide more detail about the various elements listed. A starting point for looking in this direction is here: https://sinews.siam.org/Details-Page/periodic-table-of-the-finite-elements I would specifically look into the book by Arnold and Winther on exterior calculus.

Comment: Thank you, @Wolfgang Bangerth! I will check the references you suggested.

Comment: Such a good answer.